# Using Security Rules in Firebase to Limit Access in a Social Media App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am implementing a social media app where people make posts and others can upvote/downvote them. I am using Firebase Realtime Database. I want authenticated users to be able to add posts and change the score of other posts by upvoting or downvoting but I don't want them to be able to change the contents of or delete other posts. Is there a way to give users access to add new posts without letting them change existing posts? Also is there a way to make sure that when users change the score of a post they only increment or decrement it? I was thinking of doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    "posts": {
      ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
      "$postID": {
        "$score": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && (newData.val() == $score + 1 || newData.val() == $score - 1)" 
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*please limit yourself to one question per post*

> is there a way to make sure that when users change the score of a post they only increment or decrement it?

Yes that is possible, but in your code you're comparing `newData.val()` (the new value) to `$score`, which is the key (string) of the node. You'll want to compare against `data.val()` instead, so:

```
".validate": "newData.isNumber() && (
    newData.val() == data.val() + 1 || 
    newData.val() == data.val() - 1
)"
```

Note btw that `.validate` rules are *not* evaluated when a node is deleted, so you might want to do this in the `.write` rule if it should also prevent deletes.